# OpenSSL private, public key and certificate, what exactly do i send to client?

Tags: linux, ssl, boost, openssl

I am starting out with SSL.

I have created server and client applications accord to [this](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/ssl/client.cpp) and [this](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/ssl/server.cpp) example.

Searched the internet for some information about the keys and certificates.
Found this command `openssl req -x509 -nodes -days 365 -newkey rsa:1024 -keyout mycert.pem -out mycert.pem` which i used for both, the server and client sides and it seems to work.

I opened the cert.pem file to find out, that this file contains both, private key and certificate data. I think giving out private key is a bad thing, so there must be something wrong with what i did. AND i didnt see a public key in there.

Then i found [this](https://www.openssl.org/docs/HOWTO/keys.txt) short guide on how to create private key. All good (i refused to use the version which asks password). Now i see the file contains only private key.

NEXT

I find [this](https://www.openssl.org/docs/HOWTO/certificates.txt) short guide on certificates. Following step 4 i created a certificate using the previously generated private key. Checked the file, confirmed there was only certificate data in it. Great. I started thinking, i finally need a public key which i can send to client machine. Then i noticed something, inside that guide, it says `Certificates are related to public key cryptography by containing a public key.` Hmm, i open the file with application called 'View files' and it shows me the certificate details i entered while creating it and there IS a section called 'public key' and it has data.

So, while thinking i'm all good and done, i send this certificate file to client machine, run server (OK), run client (FAIL), says `handshaking failed`.

Well then, i quickly find a command to create a public key out of my private key. Append it to the certificate file and send to client. Server (OK), client (OK). So it seems it couldnt extract public key out from the certificate.

I then tried to use only a public key at the client side - no certificate. Client failed, so it has to have both, public key and cert. In case i have gone blind for a moment, i checked the public key which i generated with the data about the public key inside the certificate and found they didn't match.

SO the questions are, am i correct to send public key concatenated with certificate to a client?
Why did client application not use the public key inside the certificate itself?
Am i doing the whole thing correctly.
Is all the traffic between server and client secured this way (using private + cert on server and pubic + cert on client)?

Anyone can open the .pem file (with said 'View file' program) and read what the certificate holds (like country, city, organisation and so on). Are certificates meant to be available like so?

**EDIT 1**

According to current answers i see i have provided too little information. I will try to do that in this edit.

I have zero experience with SSL and all i knew before this work is that SSL made connections between browser and web server secure by encrypting it.

I was given a task to upgrade our server to include SSL. Brief description of server:

It is a piece of hardware + software with linux being as platform. It is an industry type PC. The software works as server which has no GUI and sends and receives data through TCP/UDP.

I was given a task to include SSL connection security into the server, so clients who buy the server can connect to their client machines and have encrypted connections. I was told, that nobody wants to have their certificate stored at third party CA, so this means i do need it to be self signed. From my knowledge, clients will have to include the certificate to the trusted zone (some how) so i somehow need to send the certificate to the client, be it just let them grab the file from the server manually, or using some semi automated means.

I am using boost in every way i can, so i decided to use SSL functionality as well. This is why i checked out the examples which were provided. The actual clients may use something different which i have no control over, so i have no idea what will they use at the 'client side SSL'.

> No. It is secured via a mutually negotiated symmetric key which has
>   nothing to do with the PKI keys.

Hmm, so maybe i'm doing the wrong thing from the start. My ultimate goal is to encrypt connection using SSL. The big question is: Do i even need certificates for that?

I thought this was it, i mean private/public keys + certificate was what was needed to encrypt. But if i was wrong to think so, i will need to start looking deeper.

Answer (score 1):

> Searched the internet for some information about the keys and
> certificates. Found this command openssl req -x509 -nodes -days 365
> -newkey rsa:1024 -keyout mycert.pem -out mycert.pem which i used for both, the server and client sides and it seems to work.

The OpenSSL command `openssl req ...` creates a certificate signing request. Its meant to be signed by a trusted authority. However, you used `openssl req -x509 ...`. The `-x509` option creates a self signed certificate (rather than a request to be signed by a authority).

This is important for the next observation...

---

> So, while thinking I'm all good and done, I send this certificate file
> to client machine, run server (OK), run client (FAIL), says
> handshaking failed.

When using mutual authentication, two things happen. First, the server ca send a list of trusted authorities it accepts to certify clients. The list is a collection of Distinguished Names. Second, the client sends its certificate, if it has one that matches.

Because your client certificate is self signed, the server cannot be told to trust an authority (and the server cannot send a list of trusted self signed certificates).

I've never used mutual authentication with self signed client certificates. I believe the solution is to create an internal/private trusted authority (i.e., a CA). Then, sign the client's certificate with that CA. You can also sign the server's certificate with it.

---

> Then i found this short guide on how to create private key.

You created the private keys when you created the self signed certificates.

---

> I then tried to use only a public key at the client side - no
> certificate. Client failed, so it has to have both, public key and
> cert.

Correct. This is PKIX. You use a certificate that hold's an identity and public key (both the client and server).

I believe there's an RFC proposing the use of just public keys, but I'm only aware of deployments in email systems. For example, see [Domain-Based Email Authentication Using Public Keys Advertised in the DNS (DomainKeys)](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4870). There's also [draft-dukhovni-opportunistic-security](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-dukhovni-opportunistic-security-00), which I believe can use certificates and public keys published through DNS.

---

> SO the questions are, am i correct to send public key concatenated
> with certificate to a client?

Probably not. but I'm not entirely clear on what you are doing.

---

> Why did client application not use the public key inside the
> certificate itself?

It should. But it sounds like you overwrote the private key generated with the certificate with another private key created later. Public and private keys are a matched set, and OpenSSL will not use them if they don't match.

---

> Is all the traffic between server and client secured this way (using
> private + cert on server and pubic + cert on client)?

Hmmm.... The server has a certificate and private key. The client has a certificate and private key. The client uses the server's public key. The server uses the client's public key. So the public keys are used by the peer, and the public keys are transported by way of the X509 certs.

---

> Anyone can open the .pem file (with said 'View file' program) and read
> what the certificate holds (like country, city, organization and so
> on). Are certificates meant to be available like so?

Yes. Its considered public information intended to be published in a directory for others to find. You have to keep the private key secret, though.

Comment: I fixed a couple of little mistakes above but the server can indeed be told to trust, and send, self-signed certificates in the CertificateRequest message., which has a major effect on your answer.

Comment: No problem EJP. I was talking to one of Akami's security architects  about that a couple of days ago. He told me the server does not send the list of DNs anymore; rather the client sends its certificate. I need to dig up the standard covering that aspect of the exchange (paying particular attention to the self signed aspect).

Comment: What he says would be a violation of the TLS RFCs. These things don't just change spontaneously.

Answer (score 1):

> Am i correct to send public key concatenated with certificate to a client?

No. It's already in the certificate, and it is meaningless without that certificate.

> Why did client application not use the public key inside the certificate itself?

There's no evidence here that it didn't, and no reason why it wouldn't.

> Am i doing the whole thing correctly.

Impossible to say. You've only made vague statements like 'sent it to server and client'. You would need to specify exactly how these files were installed at both ends.

> Is all the traffic between server and client secured this way (using private + cert on server and pubic + cert on client)?

No. It is secured via a mutually negotiated symmetric key which has nothing to do with the PKI keys.

> Anyone can open the .pem file (with said 'View file' program) and read what the certificate holds (like country, city, organisation and so on). Are certificates meant to be available like so?

Yes. They are public documents, describing public keys.